# How do i use vim surround from the middle of a word to the end of a line?

Tags: vim, tags, vscodevim, surround

```
printemployee.fullname(emp_1)
```

I want to use vs code vim-surround to give me this result:

```
print(emloyee.fullname(emp_1)
```

I've tried `yss` from the cursor on `e` but that wraps the whole line.

I've tried `ysw` from the cursor on `e` but that only wraps `( employee )`.

I've tried `ysiw` from the cursor on `e` but that wraps `( printemployee )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to insert a `(` before the cursor, as per your example, then Surround is useless.

If the missing `)` is a typo (which is likely given the missing `p` in `employee`) and you actually want:

```
print(employee.fullname(emp_1))
```

then you should do:

```
ys$)
```

which literally reads as "surround the text from here to the end of the line with parentheses".

Note that this is not specific to Surround. `ys` is an *operator* provided by Surround that operates on the text covered by the motion you give it, like the native `y` or `d`.

The motion you want is right there in the title of your question: "to the end of the line", so there is no point using random motions with vastly different semantics. Neither of the following motion could be expected to fit the bill:

- `w`, which means "from the cursor to the first character of next word",
- `iw`, which means "the current word",

so using them is pointless.

And `yss` rather explicitly [covers](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround/blob/master/doc/surround.txt#L60-L64) the entire line, which makes it useless.

The right motion, here, is [`$`](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/blob/master/ROADMAP.md#left-right-motions), for "to the end of the line".

Comment: Why use a Vim emulator if you don't know how to use Vim?

Comment: Vim emulators are the shallow end you can enter instead of taking the deep dive.

Maybe you don't agree with this approach, but some people prefer it that way.

Comment: More like inflatable garden pools.

Comment: Well some people need shallow pools to lose their fear of water. The more people are lead to vim via emulation, the better. Or not?